# What does the phrase "feel native to" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "feel native to" in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game "KartRider Rush+":

> You will find that the fundamental chassis of gameplay is similar to
>   the PC version of the game, but KartRider Rush+ has never been this
>   visceral; the intuitive controls of the game feel native to the iPhone
>   and iPad.

I came across the following meanings of the word "native" on [[Word Reference][1](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/native)](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/native):

> designed for use with a specific type of computer:
>
> *writing native applications for 32-bit PCs.*
>
> internal to a specific application program:
>
> *to view the file in its native format.*

However, I am not sure as to how do these meanings fit in the given context.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The original meaning of "native" means "born in this country/region"

When applied to software, it means "created for this hardware"

So software that is native to the iPhone was originally written to run on an iPhone, and isn't adapted or ported from some other system.

Native software will make often better use of hardware and the interface will seem more natural than in badly migrated or ported software.

So your quote means that "KartRider Rush+" (which was originally a PC game) has been ported very well, so much so that it seems like a native iPhone game.